# SQL/PHP Basic Data Saving

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to learn the real basics of SQL and PHP. Right now, I'm trying to create a basic CMS from scratch (as I find I tend to learn better by applying things right out the gate).

To begin, I'm looking to save the name of the website (which is displayed as an H1 on the homepage). In my database, would I just create a new column called "website_name"? This seems like a waste seeing as how there will only ever be one value, but as far as I can tell this is the only way to do it.

Next, what would be the best way to locate website_name in a database called cms where there is only one value saved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler Williams, if you want learn about php and mysql, i recomend you start with the basics.
CMS not are indicated for that.
Need some more specific knowleadge.
Perhaps, if you needs start with it, try http://learnscratch.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a database in your case. Simple use GLOBAL variables. You can create a file to be imported as a 'config' into you pages. Take a look at this page from W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp